# how to a translatable string in drupal theme?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-theming

I want to put a string as a signature in drupal theme I am working on. the website is multilingual and the string should be translated based on the current language of the website. I don't know how to do it.

my drupal version is 6.

Would you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your message in the t() function.
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/t/6

Then see this page for a brief guide on localizing:
http://drupal.org/node/322729